# How to put maven project version in log file name (log4j.xml)

Tags: maven, maven-2, log4j2

I want to generate log file according to maven project version.

In the the log4j.xml file I add the following line:

```
<appender name="rollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/ussdMoneyTransfert_logFile${project.version}.log" />
</appender>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: <appender name="rollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/ussdMoneyTransfert_logFile${project.version}.log" />
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <!-- Keep one backup file -->
  <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %t %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

Comment: accept the answer. if it answers for you

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by enabling [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

When resource filtering is enabled, Maven, by default, is replacing all occurences of `${...}` with a property value (if one exist for that name). Properties can come from the system properties, your project properties, from your filter resources and from the command line.

`${project.version}` is one property that Maven adds during the build. It will be replaced by the current Maven project version during filtering.

Comment: @AMALJERBI Happy to help. Consider upvoting and accepting this answer if this resolved your problem successfully.

Answer (score 0):

after enabling resource filtering in springboot i change ${project.version} to @project.version@ and it works fine!.

Comment: Please put more context in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple... Let's says you have a pom.xml and log4j2.yml

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven....Schema-instance"
    ....
    <artifactId>ArtifactName</artifactId>
    <version>2.36.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Add `@project.version@` to the log file name this will append the version to the actual log file name.

log4j2.yml

```
Configuration:
  name: "AppName"
  monitorInterval: 30
  status: info
  ....
  RollingFile:
      - name: json-log-file
        fileName: "${sys:tomcat.log.dir}/${app_log}-@project.version@.log.json"
        filePattern: "${app_log}-@project.version@-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
```

If you noticed this is reading it from pom.xml directly, where the project is parent tag and the version is child tag.