# Log4j2 configuration - indentify the webapp

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

In my webapp I configure Log4j2 with XML file.

The case is there's might be several versions of this webapp deployed on the server (for production purpose). If I don't edit log4j2 configuration, all webapps write logs to the same location.

So I need somehow identify versions of the app and add this identifier to the end of the folder name.
Apps always have different names, so maybe I can use it.

Can anyone please suggests some solution for this?

P. S. I know I could use ${log4j:configParentLocation} or something like this, but this gives me troubles when I deploy the app.

Edit: I don't use Spring boot, just usual Tomcat Servlet webapp with web.xml.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put maven project version in log file name (log4j.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395597/how-to-put-maven-project-version-in-log-file-name-log4j-xml)

Comment: @Joe No, I don't need Maven version, because it's always the same

Comment: you can use system properties.  Pass application name or whatever the name you want to give to your logs files through system properties and read that property in log4j2.xml file

Comment: You should use one of the [log4j2 lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) and for each version of your app set the variable's value differently.